# Command line to move folder to parent folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, command-line-interface

Windows Server 2003/ XP

Since move.exe is not buili-in in windows server 2003. Is there any way to (in command line):

```
move C:\path\to\folder C:\path\folder
```

Since the folder contains a lot files and the size is big. I don't want to copy and delete original folder.

I know this should be done by a fairly easy way, since if you cut and paste in explorer, it's instant.

Comment: Not built-in?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778084%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_m

Comment: What if I want to move subfolder as well? Seems like there's no recursive option.

Comment: It takes all children with it.  Anything that is a child of `\folder` will remain that way and will take the new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move does come with 2003. Is this what you are trying to do? (paste into command line)

```
mkdir path
mkdir path\to
mkdir path\to\folder
mkdir path\to\folder\subfolder
echo hi >path\to\folder\subfolder\file.txt
echo hi >path\to\folder\file.txt
cd path\to\
move folder ..
cd ..
dir /s /b
```

The dir at the end should show something like:

```
D:\path\folder
D:\path\to
D:\path\folder\file.txt
D:\path\folder\subfolder
D:\path\folder\subfolder\file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like [ROBOCOPY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) might do the trick for you.

"Robocopy, or "Robust File Copy", is a command-line directory replication command. It has been available as part of the Windows Resource Kit starting with Windows NT 4.0, and was introduced as a standard feature of Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. The command is literally robocopy."

Comment: Much as I love Robocopy in this instance it's not really required. Either move or xcopy is all that's required and they're both on the system by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud:

You can [create batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) that:

- [`Copy`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/copy.mspx) the file to new folder
- [`Del`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx?mfr=true)ete the file from old folder

Google, `copy.exe`, and `del.exe`, also checkout: [DOS Commands reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

Something like following(**tested**): Save as `Move.BAT`

```
@echo ON
@echo Copying...
copy /b "location1\file1" "\location2\"

@echo Verifying...
fc /b "file1" "\location2\file1"|find /i "no differences">nul

@echo Validating...
if not errorlevel 1 del file1

if not errorlevel 1 >>"file.log" echo file copied successfully
if errorlevel 1 >>"file.log" echo an error detected in "\location2\file1"
@echo Complete.
```